# How to stop execution of a while loop's condition, if the condition fails

Tags: c#, .net, oop, while-loop

I've got a while-loop, with a loop condition like so:

```
while (i != repetitionString.Length || !repetitionString[i].Equals(')'))
```

The first part of the condition checks to see that the end of the collection is not reached. Is it possible to not execute the part following `||` after the left side's condition is not met? The reason behind this is that if the left side's condition is not met, then this means that the collection is out of bounds, and hence the right side's evaluation/checking will throw an exception.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: `||` is short circuiting, so it should do this be default.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @asawyer not for false left values, use AND instead.  OR will only short circuit when the left operand is true.  Conversely, AND will only short circuit with the left operand is false.

Comment: Just for completeness sake... short circuiting works differently in VB.NET. In VB.NET, the And and Or operators do not short circuit. You have to use AndAlso and OrElse operators to get short circuiting behavior. This is to be consistent with VB6 which also didn't short circuit the And and Or operators.

Comment: @asawyer The question was to to not call the right side when the left operation is not set (false).

Comment: @Matthew I missed the not in `is not met` :)

Comment: Yes, this should be && not ||. That's the problem with double negatoves, confusing to read.

Comment: @Wolf5370 - Thanks, this is infact what I've changed it to and it worked now :) I must be too tired because it's relatively simple to figure out and makes sense now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you just simply use && instead of ||. Since the right condition is supposed to be checked only if the first one has returned true.

Comment: Thanks, this is infact what I've changed it to and it worked now :) I must be too tired because it's relatively simple to figure out and makes sense now!

Answer (score 2):

This is what will happen anyway - the boolean condition on the right is only ever executed if the left one evaluates to false. You can *force* the right one to execute as well by using binary logic ( single `|`), but that is exactly not what you want to do, so your current statement will execute just fine.

It looks like what you really want is:

```
while (i < repetitionString.Length && repetitionString[i]!=")")
{

}
```

Comment: I almost said the same thing, but after reading a bit closer I think the OP wants the opposite. He wants the right to be evaluated only if the left is met.

Comment: @Justin, but the logic seems to dictate otherwise.  First check that we haven't gotten to the end of the string, then check that the current character is also not `)`.  I think what is confusing is the OP's use of the phrase "left side's condition is not met" -- I think he's saying "not met" because he's using a `!=` operator.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not happening. The debugger is demonstrating that it's still going to the right hand side, even if the first condition is not satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Short circuiting is already occurring.

My guess is that `repetitionString` is a zero-based index, while the `.Length` returns the total count. So you'll want to modify the `if` to stay in bounds:

```
while (i != (repetitionString.Length - 1) || !repetitionString[i].Equals(')'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks equivalent to:

```
if (attribute != null || attribute.value != null)
```

because you can't use

```
if (attribute.value != null)
```

as this will raise an error when attribute == null, so I think your code is correct?

When the condition

```
i != repetitionString.Length
```

is met, the code will skip the part after the ||

Because it is an OR expression, there's no need to check the 2nd part of the condition when the first part of the condition returns true.

When you use && instead of ||, both conditions will always be checked. This is not what you want to do here.